# Max difference between two adjacent values in an array, C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to find the max difference between two adjacent values in an array.For instance, for array `int tab[6] = {1,2,8,4,5,6};` the maximum difference is `6`, because of the difference between `8` and `2`. Remaining differences are equal to `1`. So, the result of my program should be `6`. However, my program prints `1` and I do not know where's the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 6;
    int tab[6] = {1,2,8,4,5,6};
    int diff = tab[1] - tab[0], maxdiff = diff, i;

    for(i=2; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        if(diff > maxdiff)
            maxdiff = diff;

        diff = tab[i] - tab[i-1];
    }

    printf("%d\n", diff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks more like [a job for the rubber duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ... you'll do yourself a favor learning to debug things like this.

Comment: @George: but when I changed `6` to `26`, it still prints `6` instead of, in this case, `21`.

Comment: Use your debugger.

Comment: That's cuz you are printing `diff`not `maxdiff`

Comment: This task would be more interesting if  code needed to cope with `int` values over the entire range of `int` as `tab[i] - tab[i-1]` can overflow.  Of course one may use a wider integer, yet what if the task was `intmax_t tab[6]`?  Hmmm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you keep the information about the maximum difference into `maxdiff` but you always print `diff` which is the difference between the one before the last pair of numbers (in this example `1`).

`i` should goes up to `< n` otherwise you don't take into account the last pair.

- I would clean up the code a bit and check for the `n<=1` corner case.
- I guess that you are interested in the **absolute difference** among values. You either use `abs` or make sure the subtraction gives you a non-negative result by changing the order of the operands accordingly. (`abs` is easier)

Here it is  my suggestion:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  const int n = 6;
  int tab[n] = {1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 26};
  if (n <= 1)
    return 0; //or whatever you have to do in this corner case
  else {
    int maxdiff = INT_MIN;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
      maxdiff = max(maxdiff, abs(tab[i] - tab[i - 1]));

    printf("%d\n", maxdiff);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `i<n-1` will not test the difference between the final two values of `tab`
  and should be `i<n`.
- The if should be below the difference calculation to catch if the final difference calculated is the largest.
- You should be printing the `maxdiff`
- You should also be taking the absolute value in your difference calculation, to account for the first number being larger than the second (As pointed out by @Felix Palmen). You can use the `abs` function defined in `stdlib.h` or write it yourself `diff > 0? diff : -diff`.

Fixed code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 6;
    int tab[6] = {1,2,8,4,5,6};
    int diff = abs(tab[1] - tab[0]), maxdiff = diff, i;

    for(i=2; i<n; i++)
    {
        diff = abs(tab[i] - tab[i-1]);

        if(diff > maxdiff)
            maxdiff = diff;
    }

    printf("Max difference: %d\n", maxdiff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: also note the only *somewhat subtle* bug: what if you switch places for `2` and `8`?

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems. First, you're printing `diff` instead of `maxdiff`. So you're getting the result of the last diff, not the max.

Second, you're not taking the absolute value. That means `{8,2,4}` would result in 2, not 6.

Finally, though this isn't a bug, a bunch of duplication can be removed by starting with `maxdiff = 0`.

And a style note: declaring multiple variables on one line is hard to read. Declaring *and initializing* them on one line is very hard to read. Don't do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n = 6;
    int tab[] = {1,2,8,4,5,6};
    int maxdiff = 0;

    for(int i=1; i < n; i++) {
        int diff = abs(tab[i] - tab[i-1]);
        if(diff > maxdiff) {
            maxdiff = diff;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", maxdiff);

    return 0;
}
```